# MacBook Pro 2016 Display has faint horizontal line in 3/4 of screen

Tags: macbook-pro

I am suddenly starting to see this faint horizontal line in 3/4 of the screen and the Dock area, especially on dark colors and blue. They don't appear when I connect to an external port via a thunder bolt.

[image: Faint Horizontal line in 3/4 of screen]
[image]
It's just over a year old :( What could be causing this?

Comment: That indicative of an LCD display failure.  More than likely, it has to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware failure, you should go and visit an appleStore or a apple reseller to get this problem fixed.

I had the same Problem, so I went to the appleStore in Oberhausen (Germany). they repaired the Display for free.

Comment: That's what I was scared of, don't know if they would have any such policy here. Apple support in India sucks.

Comment: Just ask. I Don't think that there will be a problem.